# Where have all the projected national CRSs gone in QGIS 3.4.3?

Tags: coordinate-system

I have been working with different geographic projections in QGIS 3.4.3.  I cannot find any Australian national geographic projections, such as GDA94Z55 in the new version. They were there in QGIS 3.4.2.

Any clues as to how I can access them so they are part of the default CRSs in the program?

Comment: Opening any old project using these CRS should add them to your repository. To be sure you can access them from new projects, save them as your own CRS.

Comment: If you are referring to [EPSG:28355](https://epsg.io/28355), I can found it in QGIS 3.4.3 CRSs. Search for it by the EPSG code.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel and Erik.  These used to be a lot more obvious in previous QGIS versions.  One shouldn't have to search for them in old QGIS projects.